# insert data from 3 tables with the same fields into 1 table

Tags: mysql, sql, insert, insert-into

I have 3 tables (`accnt`, `jobcost`, and `servic15`). all with the same fields (`code`, `jno`, `ven`, `date`). I need to insert the data from these tables into another table called dummy with the same fields, in one query. how do I do this?

i have used 3 separate insert into statements that look like this: but i need it in one statement:

```
INSERT INTO dbo.dummy
SELECT
dbo.jobcost.code,
dbo.jobcost.ven,
dbo.jobcost.date,
dbo.jobcost.jno,
FROM 
dbo.jobcost
WHERE
dbo.jobcost.jno > '40000'
```

---

```
INSERT INTO dbo.dummy
SELECT
dbo.servic15.code,
dbo.servic15.ven,
dbo.servic15.date,
dbo.servic15.jno
FROM 
dbo.servic15
WHERE
```

### `dbo.servic15.jno > '40000'`

```
INSERT INTO dbo.dummy
SELECT
dbo.accnt.code,
dbo.accnt.ven,
dbo.accnt.date,
dbo.accnt.jno
FROM 
dbo.accnt
WHERE
dbo.jobcost.jno > '40000'
```

Comment: Post what you've tried.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need [INSERT ... SELECT](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/insert-select.html) statement

```
INSERT INTO dummy  (code, jno, ven, date)
  SELECT code, jno, ven, date FROM accnt jno > '40000'
  UNION ALL
  SELECT code, jno, ven, date FROM jobcost jno > '40000'
  UNION ALL
  SELECT code, jno, ven, date FROM servic15 jno > '40000';
```

If the table is not created yet, use  [CREATE TABLE ... SELECT](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/create-table-select.html).

Comment: when i do this, it tells me this:  
All queries combined using a UNION, INTERSECT or EXCEPT operator must have an equal number of expressions in their target lists.                 Could this be because accnt has one extra field called "imported" that I dont want to insert into the new table?

Comment: @samhatcher your tables doesnt have same structure, try edited answer

Comment: ok, that worked. now how do I tell it to only take the records with a jno > 40000

Answer (score 0):

```
INSERT INTO dummy  (code, invno, ven, invdate, amon, accno, amnt, jno, saccno, ckno)
  SELECT code, invno, ven, invdate, amon, accno, amnt, jno, saccno, ckno FROM accnt 
  WHERE jno > '40000'
  UNION ALL
  SELECT code, invno, ven, invdate, amon, accno, amnt, jno, saccno, ckno FROM jobcost 
  WHERE jno > '40000'
  UNION ALL
  SELECT code, invno, ven, invdate, amon, accno, amnt, jno, saccno, ckno FROM servic15 
  WHERE jno > '40000';
```

this worked